# pthread_barrier doesn't work properly (in C)

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a main function which initialize a pthread_barrier as the following:

```
pthread_barrier_t     barrier;
pthread_barrierattr_t attr;

if (pthread_barrierattr_init(&attr) != 0 ||
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, &attr, nb_threads) != 0)
  return ;
int i = 0;
while (i < nb_threads)
    {
      threads[i].barrier = &barrier;
      threads[i].attr = &attr;
      // ...
      if ((error = pthread_create(&threads[i].thread, NULL, core,
                                  (void *)&threads[i])) != 0)
        return (thread_create_error(error));
      i++;
    }
  i = -1;
  while (++i < nb_philo)
    pthread_join(threads[i].thread, NULL);
```

And, in each thread, I have a pointer on my barrier variables.

And, in each thread's function (the same one for each thread), I have the `pthread_barrier_wait(thread->barrier)` function within a loop.

```
void thread_func(...)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < nb_threads)
    {
       //...Doing some stuff
       pthread_barrier_wait(thread->barrier)
       i++;
    }
}
```

In most of case, it works very well, but very rarely (and randomly??), it outputs nothing, the program is stuck, it seems like the barrier is still waiting. Sometimes, the `pthread_barrier_wait(thread->barrier)` functions returns -1 (most of case it returns 0).

How could I fix this problem ? It this the good way to use barriers in C ? There is no mutex, is this normal ? Why sometimes the program still waits and sometimes no ?

The output seems to work at the beginning, and after few iterations, it completely fails :

```
thread 1 begin
thread 2 begin
thread 3 begin
...
thread 1 end
thread 2 end
thread 3 end
...

after few iterations:

thread 1 begin
thread 2 begin
thread 3 end

...

thread 3 begin
thread 1 end
thread 2 end
...
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you initialize `attr`? Because that's missing from your code and if its a local variable, the contents are otherwise undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I missed this initialization, but unfortunately there is still the same problem (once again : not always, but in rarely case, the function is stuck) Btw I updated my post

Comment: What does `perror` prints when it returns -1?

Comment: Do you wait for all threads to join? I see it's going up to `nb_philo`. Is this the same as `nb_threads`?

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to reproduce now.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, nb_philo = nb_threads, btw I have uptated the post, I add the output: The beginning seems to work, then It fails after few iterations, Thank you